# Attaching VisualVM or JConsole to Java in Docker on GCE

Tags: java, docker, google-compute-engine, jmx, visualvm

I am trying to get some CPU sampling working on a remote Java-in-Docker process.

I've already looked at the related questions here, and tried everything, to no avail, so I'm posting my setup here.

I have a Java process (openjdk-8) running in a Docker container on a Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance.  The GCE instance and container are both running Debian-9.  I want to attach VisualVM or JConsole to my Java process.

I am able to run my docker container locally and connect with both visualvm and jconsole using localhost:9010.

I start the container in the VM startup script with:

```
docker run -d -p 9010:9010 <my container>
```

The Dockerfile also has:

```
EXPOSE 9010
```

The Java process, started by the Dockerfile CMD, has the following relevant args:

```
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false", \
```

I have opened up port 9010 in my gcloud firewall using:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create jmx-port --allow=tcp:9010,udp:9010
```

I have verified with netcat that the port is open and I can make a TCP connection to it.

I have other ports open from the same Docker container, with clients connecting successfully to those ports.  They were exposed and mapped to the host ports the same way (-p port:port) and opened in the firewall the same way.

I am passing the external IP address of the GCE instance.  For instance, if I do:

```
gcloud compute instances list
```

and it tells me:

```
NAME            ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP      STATUS
my-server-b23j  us-central1-d  n1-standard-1               10.240.0.2   108.357.213.99   RUNNING
```

Then I will use the argument:

```
108.357.213.99:9010
```

as the remote jmx connection host:port pair.

VisualVM and JConsole both tell me they can't connect to the remote JMX service.  In both cases, I decline the secure connection, and then they say:

```
Cannot connect to 108.357.213.99:9010 using
service:jmx:rmi:////jndi/rmi://108.357.213.99:9010/jmxrmi
```

In desperation, I added a firewall rule that enables TCP/UDP connections on all ports 0-65535, but it did not make a difference -- they still could not connect.

I've read that JMX-RMI opens up anonymous ports, and that you can (at least partly?) disable this behavior by specifying both:

```
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010", \
```

However, it doesn't do the trick in my case.

I've read [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/enable-jmx-rmi-access-to-a-docker-container/625/5) that you need to specify the rmi server hostname:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname='192.168.99.100'
```

but my server IP is ephemeral -- it is assigned by Google Compute Engine when I create the instance, and so I can't hardwire it into the Dockerfile with the rest of the Java args.

Am I going to have to get a static IP address to make this work?

Comment: Generally visualvm works best on the same host.  Can you execute it inside the cloud instance?

Answer (score 6):

One possible solution would be to ssh into your GCE box and port-forward port 9010. This can be done from the local console with:

```
gcloud compute ssh name-of-your-gce-engine -- -L 9010:localhost:9010
```

Then in `jconsole` or `jvisualvm` you connect to `localhost:9010`. Using localhost here means that `jconsole/jvisualvm` will connect to your local machine, this connect is tunneled by ssh into your GCE engine and there to the host and port defined in the `-L` argument, which is `localhost:9010`, but from the GCE-engine's view. Meaning that you will end up at your application.

You still have to set the rmi server name before starting your program, but you must use

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname='localhost'
```

so that RMI will tell `jconsole/jvisualvm`  to use localhost and this will then resolve to your local tunneled endpoint. And of course you still need these:

```
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false", \
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false", \
```

Comment: Thanks -- I will try this ASAP and let you know if it works.